# бинарное дерево с негативными числами

Tags: java, binary, дерево

Как написать код для binary tree с негативными числами ? Может есть примеры ?

Comment: Если речь идёт о значениях в узлах - то какая разница, отрицательные они или положительные?

Answer (score 0):

Вот обычная простая реализация:

```
public class Node {

    private int value;
    private Node parent;
    private Node leftChild;
    private Node rightChild;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Node getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Node parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Node getLeftChild() {
        return leftChild;
    }

    public void setLeftChild(Node leftChild) {
        this.leftChild = leftChild;
    }

    public Node getRightChild() {
        return rightChild;
    }

    public void setRightChild(Node rightChild) {
        this.rightChild = rightChild;
    }

}

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node parent = new Node();
        parent.setValue(1);

        Node leftChild = new Node();
        leftChild.setValue(2);

        Node rightChild = new Node();
        rightChild.setValue(3);

        parent.setLeftChild(leftChild);
        parent.setRightChild(rightChild);
        leftChild.setParent(parent);
        rightChild.setParent(parent);
    }

}
```

А насчет того, что отрицательные числа в дереве, то вы можете в сеттере проверять входящее значение или если Spring, то Spring validation.